# How to disable a checkbox in a DevExpress grid

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, grid, devexpress

I have a devexpress grid with a column that shows up as a checkbox.  How can I disable this checkbox so that the user is not able to click on it, but it still displays a check or a blank box?

Comment: `<CheckBox IsEnabled="False"/>` What kind of question is this?

Comment: That wont work for `WinForms`.

Comment: @dozer789 right, I just tend to forget jurassic park type of stuff.

Comment: @SeanSmyth please make sure to use the proper tags. If you're using winforms, then tag your question winforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that column will be `Boolean Column`. Try setting `Column.ColumnEdit` to `TextEdit` It will display true or false instead showing `CheckEdit`.

By default `Boolean column` uses `checkedit` in devexpress grid that makes sense.

Note: I've not tested try it out

Comment: Is there a way to keep the checkbox as the display control, but just have it disabled?

Comment: I think you have to handle RowCellStyle event and find your column and set e.Appearance

Comment: @SeanSmyth check this link http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q50116